# JMeter - Variable is resetting in each loop (Regular Expression Extractor)

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test Plan like this:

[My Test Plan in JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElRSD.png)

As you can see, I have a **myarray** variable to get all the matches in the Loop Controller. In each loop myarray variable resets its content so I only get the last loop's myarray content to process in ForEach Controller. How can I add each loop's myarray content to over each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `${__counter(,)}` to the existing Reference Name in Regular Expression Extractor.

Example:

```
Reference name: myarray_${__counter(,)}
```

so, for each loop new reference name will be used and hence previous iterations results will be saved.

first loop results: myarray_1
second loop results: myarray_2
etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Naveen. But I want to access all loop's arrays in a single array so I can run ForEach for that merged Array.

Comment: I don't think there is built-in support to achieve what you asked for. But work around is, add two `For Each controller`, nested, so `Outer For Each controller` to iterate over all the loops' myarray and `Inner For Each controller` to iterate over the values inside the `myarray`

Comment: That ForEach inside ForEach is a good idea. I will try it. I think it will resolve my issue. Thanks Naveen.